# Quartz CronTrigger ignores misfire policies and reschedules every misfire

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, misfire-instruction

I have created a CronTrigger in following way

```
CronScheduleBuilder schedule = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(new CronExpression(CRON_EXPRESSION)).withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing();
```

From what I've read [here about Cron Triggers](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html), if I would have a server shutdown, during which would normally be the CronTrigger fired several times, when the server comes back online, I should have the Quartz Job executed only with the next normally scheduled trigger fire.

This actually does not work the expected way and it does not matter what policy I set, I have the Job executed all the times the trigger was misfired. So if trigger misfired 100 times, I get the job executed 100 times. Is this really a bug or am I doing something wrong?

*I am using Quartz-scheduler 2.2.1 on WebSphere with SimpleThreadPool, JobStoreTX, StdJDBCDelegate, isClustered=true, threadCount=1*